# What is String.LegacyMode property for exactly?

Tags: c#, .net, string, legacy

When I decompile [`String.IndexOf (String)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method, I see this;

```
[__DynamicallyInvokable]
public int IndexOf(string value)
{
  return this.IndexOf(value, string.LegacyMode ? StringComparison.Ordinal : StringComparison.CurrentCulture);
}
```

In the second parameter definition:

- if `string.LegacyMode` is `true`, `StringComparison.Ordinal` is evaluated.
- if `string.LegacyMode` is `false`, `StringComparison.CurrentCulture` is evaluated.

But what does `String.LegacyMode` exactly mean?

When I decompile this property I see this:

```
internal static bool LegacyMode
{
  get
  {
    return CompatibilitySwitches.IsAppEarlierThanSilverlight4;
  }
}
```

I searched about [String.LegacyMode](https://www.google.com.tr/search?q=string.LegacyMode&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&gws_rd=cr&ei=rxZmUt6qLcWa0AXtg4DIAg#q=String.LegacyMode&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official) and [CompatibilitySwitches.IsAppEarlierThanSilverlight4](https://www.google.com.tr/search?q=CompatibilitySwitches.IsAppEarlierThanSilverlight4&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&gws_rd=cr&ei=3BpmUvbBCMWf0QXGroGIDg) on Google first but I couldn't find any useful information.

Can you enlighten me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not check the source, MSDN :)

Ninja edit: I just saw the link you posted at the top of your question. Select Silverlight from the other versions dropdown and you'll see the note below.

[String.IndexOf Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

> Notes to Callers
>
> Starting in Silverlight 4, the behavior of the String.IndexOf(String) method has changed. In Silverlight 4, it performs a case-sensitive and culture-sensitive comparison using the current culture to find the first occurrence of value. This conforms to the behavior of the String.IndexOf(String) method in the full .NET Framework. In Silverlight 2 and Silverlight 3, String.IndexOf(String) performs an ordinal comparison. If the common language runtime determines that a Silverlight-based application was compiled using either Silverlight 2 or Silverlight 3, it performs an ordinal comparison; otherwise, it performs a culture-sensitive comparison.